# R Studio says TRUE for one thing and FALSE for the exact same thing

Tags: r, date, variables

Sorry if this is silly, but I don't understand how R Studio is seeing one statement as True and the same statement false. How do I get R to see

`print(as.Date(test) <= as.Date(2022-10-12))`

as being TRUE? When I test with the same date raw it says TRUE (see pictures).
What am I missing?
I'm using RStudio 2023.03.0 Build 286, and R 4.3.2

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is "UTC" included in the `test` variable?

Comment: `2022-9-29` is the number `2022` minus `9` minus `29`, which is `1984`, and is less than `as.Date(2022-10-12)`, which similarly comes out to `2000` (`2022 - 10 - 12`).

Comment: The dates need to be quoted.  As is, they are being treated as an arithmetic expression where `test` looks to already be a date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`as.Date` takes as input a date format of class `"character"`

The following is seen as 3 numbers with a minus sign

```
2022-10-12
[1] 2000
```

which results in

```
as.Date(2022-10-12)
[1] "1975-06-24"
```

that's 2000 days after "1970-01-01".

This is how it should be

```
test <- "2022-09-29"

as.Date(test) <= as.Date("2022-10-12")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Oh! I see now! I was so focused on "test" being the problem, I didn't consider the quotes around the date being the issue. Thank you so much for explaining!